# as we're going through

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Myridon: "like a block, esp in shape and solidarity" is pretty funny ***as*** we're going through the exercise in this thread of showing that "block" isn't a shape.

Source: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/anvil-a-heavy-iron-block-on-which.3931328/#post-20125217

---

I'm not sure if "***as***" means *when* or *because* in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both can correct. Try substituting "when" in:

> "like a block, esp in shape and solidarity" is pretty funny **when** we're going through the exercise in this thread of showing that "block" isn't a shape

It still holds the meaning of the original sentence, now try "because":

> "like a block, esp in shape and solidarity" is pretty funny **because** we're going through the exercise in this thread of showing that "block" isn't a shape

The meaning still holds true, so both can be used. "because" may be *slightly* more accurate here, so it might be better to interpret it as "because", mostly because of the fact that the sentence follows this flow:

> meaning is funny **because** we are showing block isn't a shape